# Initial value of data point must be 0 (and incremented securely)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Context: This project uses a database connected to an android app (where the app is distributed to many users)

I am attempting to ensure a user's 'points' score is set to 0 when created using createUserWithEmailAndPassword.
I kept looking for a way to ensure the value was set by the database to ensure users can't manipulate this value, since it'll be used to generate a discount for a user once a certain threshold is reached.

That search seemed fruitless so I've accepted it's likely not possible and instead I'll have to make the application set the value to 0.
Since this *can* be manipulated, I need to ensure the app can tell the difference between a value being set for the first time, and I truly cannot seem to find a way to do this.

The current architecture of the related parts of the system is:

```
Users: 
   [firebase_generated_UserID1]
       username: user12345
       points: 2
    [firebase_generated_UserID2]
       username: newUser
       points: 0 

Vouchers: 
   [VoucherCode1] 
      UserID: [UserID1] 
      Status: Valid 
   [VoucherCode2]
       UserID: [UserID1] 
      Status: Claimed
```

So my aims are that:

the points value is 0 for new users;
 points value is added to securely;  
points value is securely subtracted by a fixed number when a voucher is added for a user.

Since I'm not even fully sure if this is possible, I'm happy to hear any input on what I may be doing wrong

I have been hesitant to use Cloud Functions since I know it requires upgrading to the pay-as-you-go tier, and this project does have a budget of 0 (lol). The risk that we go over our limits and are on the hook for billing has left me searching for alternatives like this

Answer (score 1):

> I am attempting to ensure a user's 'points' score is set to 0 when
> created using createUserWithEmailAndPassword.

You can use a Cloud Function [triggered when a Firebase user is created in your project](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events?hl=en&authuser=0#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation).

Cloud Functions execute in the back-end and bypass any security rules. Therefore if you set RTDB security rules which prevent users modifying the RTDB `Users/[userID]` sub-nodes you can be sure users will not be able to "manipulate" point values. Note that this means that each update of the points sub-nodes (i.e. the "incrementation") must be done via a Cloud Function (e.g. a Callable Cloud Function, an RTDB triggered one or a Firestore triggered one).

> I have been hesitant to use Cloud Functions since I know it requires
> upgrading to the pay-as-you-go tier, and this project does have a
> budget of 0

Cloud Functions have a free tier of 2 millions invocations a month, so you should not pay anything (unless your app becomes very famous, which I wish you). However you need a credit card to activate Cloud Functions (i.e. "upgrading to the pay-as-you-go tier"), even if there is no cost.